# unknown pieces of a set - stickers on round corner bricks

Tags: set-identification

I have found these pieces in a bulk purchase and I would like to find out the set.
They have sticker on it. Maybe a star wars set?
many thanks

[image: corner pieces]

Answer (score 6):

[9450 Epic Dragon Battle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9450-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) is the only set that contains part [95188pb12L - Brick, Round Corner 6 x 6 with Slope 33 Edge, Facet Cutout with 3 Diamonds and Black Line Pattern Model Left Side (Sticker) - Set 9450](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=95188pb12L&in=S)

[image]

Comment: Great. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [95188pb12L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=112952) leading to set [9450 Epic Dragon Battle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9450-1)

[image: 9450]